# How to ROS_*_THROTTLE inside objects?

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a vector of objects of a custom class.  In one function of my class, I am trying to include a [ROS_*_THROTTLE macro](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging). At some point, I iterate through the vector, calling my function.  I would like for the message to get printed once for each object, but instead the message only gets called for the very first object, leading me to believe the throttle isn't based on the message content or the context, but rather the line number or something like that. Am I correct on this?

If so, is there any existing way to throttle messages per object or per message content? I tried using named loggers, too, but still I only get the one message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218809/how-to-ros_*_throttle-inside-objects?/) by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3562 on 2015-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else trying to find the answer to this in the future: it doesn't appear to be possible, but there's a workaround.

The [ROS_LOG_THROTTLE](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rosconsole/html/console_8h.html#abcd24e58d38c9018c49118ea6619020e) macro statically defines `last_hit`, so there's only one timer per invocation of that line (regardless of whether you try a `ROS_*_THROTTLE_NAMED` call as well).

My suggestion would be to manually throttle it using `ROS_*_COND` instead. It's unsatisfactory, but it seems to be the best solution.

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0